# How to phrase "it took two hours"?

Tags: idiom, time, finnish

In English or Finnish I can express the time it took to complete something in two ways, but in Latin only one:

1. E: "I did it in two hours."
   F: "Tein sen kahdessa tunnissa."
   L: *Duabus horis id perfeci.*
2. E: "It took me two hours to do it."
   F: "Minulta kesti kaksi tuntia tehdä se."
   L: ***???***

The first phrasing expresses simply that something was completed in some time.
The second one gives more emphasis to the amount of time and often indicates that the time was longer than expected.

Can I express the second one in Latin?
What is a Latin way to phrase "take" when something takes time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FWIW, the verb **[consumo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconsumo)**, can be used with amounts of time as meaning *to spend*:

> horasque multas saepe suavissimo sermone consumeres ([Cic. Fam. 11.27.5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:phi,0474,056:11:27:5))

Hence a possibility is to say you *spent* two hours: **horas duas consumpsi id faciens**