# To get over a trauma OR just learn to live with it

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Are there Latin idioms for getting over a trauma and/ or learning to live with one?

Here's a made-up sentence:

> A widow said that it had taken her a year to get over the death of her husband; or, not so much 'get over' as just learn to live with it, which isn't quite the same thing.

A possible translation:

> vidua dixit unum annum consumpsisse convalescere ex morte mariti, deinde non tantum 'convalescere' quam eam pati posse, quas res non easdem sint.

A widow said that it had consumed a year to recover from the death of her husband; then, not so much 'recover' as to be able to endure it; these circumstances not being quite the same (thing).

Does the Latin translation work?

Comment: due to further research, but one can consider other options than *consumere*. it seems to somewhat implying a deliberate action that was taken to *invest* (or sometimes even worse in negative connotation to *waste*); note that even in English the voice is passive/impersonal.  maybe something *prius circumactus est annus quam potest convalescere ...* ; or something like "she needed a year to recover"; Anyway, if *consumere* is used not sure the infinitive after is the most classical choice. One can also consider *(se/animum) colligo* instead of *convalesco* which tends to be more of the psychi.

Comment: @d_e: Is there something missing? What came before, "...due to further research,"? Verb, "consumere", was featured in this answer, Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6851/1982, for "time taken". Thanks for the alternative translations: "until a year has been turned around that she is able to recover". Verb, "convalesco, tends to be more of the psychic", Oxford gives: "recover"; "get better"; "grow strong"; these, of course, may also apply to matters of the mind.

Comment: sorry for bad phrasing. the linked answer there has *spend*  for active *consemere*. Is there a diff between "it had taken her a year .." and "She spent a year"? that's what I was alluding to. But not sure the point holds hence "due to further research";;; Now, I believe *convalescere* is completely okay (though I yet to see one example where the recovery is psychological after shock), so here I just wanted to add another option which is more particular for things of the mind than a general *convalesco* .

Comment: What I meant with "Anyway, if *consumere* is used not sure the infinitive after is the most classical choice"; is not agaisnt the verb *convalescere* itself (which as I said  is probably very good) but the very usage of the infinitive  *form*.

Comment: @d_e: How about, "...consumpsisse ut convalescere possit ex morte..."; a result clause with a present subjunctive (historic-present consequence of the recovery--in the past; not violating sequence-of-tense). I wasn't sure about "ex morte" or just, "morte"--does it make a difference? Thanks again.

Comment: I guess that's better but don;t know. in [L&S dictionary](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=consumo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) there are examples with "in + abl" so maybe *in convalescendo* will also work.